# How to use Promise.all in the following readFile code?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

In the following code, I'm reading some files and getting their filename and text. After that, I'm storing data in an option variable to generate an epub file:

```
const Epub = require("epub-gen")
const folder = './files/'
const fs = require('fs')
let content = []

fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(filename => {
    const title = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
    const data = fs.readFileSync(`${folder}${filename}`).toString('utf-8')
    content.push({ title, data })
  })
})

const option = {
  title: "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland", // *Required, title of the book.
  content
}

new Epub(option, "./text.epub")
```

The problem is, `new Epub` runs before the files are read, before `content` is ready. I think `Promise.all` is the right candidate here. I checked the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) docs. But it shows various promises as example, but I have none. So, I'm not very sure how to use `Promise.all` here.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add promises to an array.  Each promise should resolve with the value you were pushing into `content`

When all promises resolve, the returned value will be the array previously known as `content`.

Also, you can, and should, use all async `fs` calls.  So `readFileSync` can be replaced with `readFile` (async).  I did not replace your code with this async call however, so you can clearly see what was required to answer your original question.

Not sure if I got the nesting right in snippet.

```
const Epub = require("epub-gen")
const folder = './files/'
const fs = require('fs')

let promises = []

fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(filename => {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const title = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
      const data = fs.readFile(`${folder}${filename}`).toString('utf-8')
      resolve({
        title,
        data
      })

    }))
  })
})

const option = {
  title: "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland", // *Required, title of the book.
  content
}

new Epub(option, "./text.epub")

Promise.all(promises).then((content) => {
  //done
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with `readdir`, which is asynchronous so `new Epub`, like you already figured out, is called *before* it's `callback` parameter.

Switch to using `readdirSync` or move `const option ... new Epub...` inside the `callback` parameter of `readdir`, after `files.forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can do everything synchronous since you use readFileSync.
So you can place the Epub creation after the forEach loop.

If you want to go async, my first question would be:

Does your node.js version support `util.promisify` ( node version 8.x or higher iirc )?
If so, that can be used to turn the callback functions like readFile and such into promises. If not, you can use the same logic, but then with nested callbacks like the other solutions show.

```js
const FS = require( 'fs' );
const { promisify } = require( 'util' );
const readFile = promisify( FS.readFile );
const readFolder = promisify( FS.readFolder );

readFolder( folder )
  // extract the file paths. Maybe using `/${filename}` suffices here.
  .then( files => files.map( filename => `${folder}${filename}`))
  // map the paths with readFile so we get an array with promises.
  .then( file_paths => file_paths.map( path => readFile( path )))
  // fecth all the promises using Promise.all() .
  .then( file_promises => Promise.all( file_promises ))
  .then( data => {
    // do something with the data array that is returned, like extracting the title.
    // create the Epub objects by mapping the data values with their titles
  })
  // error handling.
  .catch( err => console.error( err ));
```